# How to save with django model form multiple data into one table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a model to save the reservation data with a form model and it works very well but only for one person. I would like that when the number of people exceeds a person the form asks the same data for the following people in the same form with the same model (Table).

I have tried to create multiple model to save data depending the number of people but it's not what I want because I want to do this with one model I mean one table from the database.

This is my model:

```
class BusTicket(models.Model):
'''
Class to define a bus ticket
'''
vip_types = (
    ('Yes', 'Yes'),
    ('No', 'No'),
    )
#each indivitual status 
PENDING = 'Pending'
CONFIRMED = 'Confrimed'

TICKET_STATUSES = ((PENDING,'Pending'),
    (CONFIRMED,'Confrimed'),
    )
vip_booking = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=vip_types, default="No")
gender      = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=gender_choices)
first_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
last_name   = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
email       = models.EmailField(max_length = 254)
active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
update      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
bus_id      = models.ForeignKey(BusTravels, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
phone_number = PhoneNumberField() 

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name + ' ' + str(self.phone_number)
```

This is my form model to save data:

```
class BusTicketForm(forms.ModelForm):

vip_types = (
    ('Yes', 'Yes'),
    ('No', 'No'),
    )
vip_booking = forms.ChoiceField(choices=vip_types, widget=forms.RadioSelect,required=True, initial=True)

class Meta:
    model = BusTicket
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'vip_booking', 'email',  'gender',
    'phone_number', 'bus_id',]
    widgets = {
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}),
        'gender': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'phone_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone number with country code'}),
        }
```

This is my view model to handler the form:

```
def book_ticket(request, bus_id):
get_variable_model()
if request.user.is_authenticated:

    form = BusTicketForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    context = {
        'form': form
        }
    next_ = request.GET.get('next')
    next_post = request.POST.get('next')
    redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None
    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)
        form.save()

        return redirect('register-house-thanks')
        if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
            return redirect(redirect_path)
    return render(request, 'listings/sell_houses.html', context)
else:
    print("You don't have access to this page!")
    return render(request, 'accounts/notpermission.html')
```

As I said it I want to save the same data depending the number of the person who's booking a ticket from one model (table) and one form model for one post. for example if person is 1 person I will have into the form the data for one person else person is > 1 person I will have the same data for the number of person like this : 
1 Person form model data 2 Person form model data 3 Person form model data
And save those data to the model (table) from one form post data.
For one 1 Person form model data it's working correctly but I couldn't find away for multiple.
Thank you you very much for any help.